# vba pivot does not refresh after adding new lines

Tags: vba, excel

With the help of VBA I am able to create pivot table. But when new lines are added in sheet and I refresh the pivot table with `wksSource1.PivotTables(1).RefreshTable`, it is not updating the pivot table.

```
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim lastrowv As Long
Dim lastcolv As Long

lastrowv = wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolv = wksSource.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = wksSource.Cells(5, 1).Resize(lastrowv - 4, lastcolv)

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=wksSource1.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable14", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    wksSource1.Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable14").PivotFields("Term - Phases")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable14").PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable14").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable14").PivotFields("Steps/ Activities"), "Count of Steps/ Activities" _
        , xlCount
```

Answer (score -1):

wksSource1.PivotTables(1).RefreshTable will only work if the pivot cache source data is dynamic i.e. if the source data is an excel table data or a dynamic named range.

But when you are creating pivot table, the source data range is fixed and depends upon the range PRange.

So when you add new data on the source data sheet, the pivot cache still refers to the PRange which is not reset somehow.

If you are refreshing the pivot table in a sub routine, you need to update the existing pivot cache instead of refreshing the pivot table and once the pivot cache is updated, pivot table will also be updated.

Try the below code and tweak it as per your need.

```
Sub RefreshPivotTable()
Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksSource1 As Worksheet
Dim PRange As Range
Dim lastrowv As Long, lastcolv As Long

Set wksSource = Sheets("Sheet4")          'Sheet which contains the source data for pivot table

Set wksSource1 = Sheets("Sheet3")   'Sheet which contains Pivot table

lastrowv = wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolv = wksSource.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = wksSource.Range("C5:F12")

wksSource1.PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

End Sub
```